# WHM/CPANEL - High cpu and memory usage from Analog Stats

Tags: apache-2.2, cpu-usage, high-load

A single process is taking 100% of the cpu and 70% of the memory and starts every day on different account;

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/analog +CIMAGEDIR /images/ +CDOMAINSFILE /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/analog/usdom.tab +CCHARTDIR ./ +CALLCHART ON +CLANGFILE /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/analog/us.lng +COUTFILE /home/dunstar/tmp/analog/5.html +CLOCALCHARTDIR /home/dunstar/tmp/analog/ +CCACHEOUTFILE /home/dunstar/tmp/analog/cache.out +CCACHEFILE /home/dunstar/tmp/analog/cache +CVHOST ON +COSREP ON +CBROWSER ON +CFULLBROWSER ON +CREDIRREF ON +CREFSITE ON +CFAILREF ON +CLOGFORMAT COMBINED +CHOSTNAME dunstarltd.com +CHOSTURL http://dunstarltd.com/ /usr/local/apache/domlogs/dunstarltd.com.bkup
```

after i kill the process everything comes back to normal; then after 30-40 minutes another process starts for another account:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/analog +CIMAGEDIR /images/ +CDOMAINSFILE /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/analog/usdom.tab +CCHARTDIR ./ +CALLCHART ON +CLANGFILE /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/share/analog/us.lng +COUTFILE /home/pisarevo/tmp/analog/5.html +CLOCALCHARTDIR /home/pisarevo/tmp/analog/ +CCACHEOUTFILE /home/pisarevo/tmp/analog/cache.out +CCACHEFILE /home/pisarevo/tmp/analog/cache +CVHOST ON +COSREP ON +CBROWSER ON +CFULLBROWSER ON +CREDIRREF ON +CREFSITE ON +CFAILREF ON +CLOGFORMAT COMBINED +CHOSTNAME pisarevo.com +CHOSTURL http://pisarevo.com/ /usr/local/apache/domlogs/pisarevo.com.bkup
```

cpu goes high again; when we kill it all goes back to normal;

When the process starts it takes almost all the resources no matter of the site; the sites are small but have 5-20k visitors daily; the server has 8GB ram; 8 Cores;

How do we stop/deal with this ? - note all backups are currently disabled;

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analog is a statistics software like Webalizer or Awstats.

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/AnalogStats

You can disable Analog from `WHM > Statistics Software Configuration`

http://docs1.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/StatsSoftware

At the `Generators Configuration` uncheck Analog and click save.

This will disable Analog from running again.

You may also want to delete on each user's home directory any analog temp files (they tend to be a lot of MBs, even GBs!)
Those will be under `/home/_username_/tmp/analog/`

Answer (score 2):

From doing a bit of searching: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/process-run-big-memory-195311.html

Looks like it's something called "Analog Stats". You can probably disable this from within cPanel.